# How do I interpolate between points without going beyond them?

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have data of variable lengths (reaching movements recorded in 2D) and want to create a function that will resample this data to a uniform length (500 samples).

However, I want matlab to only resample between the maximum and minimum values given, without adding any additional distance. For instance, if I resample the matrix `[1:1:10]`, the resampled matrix should have a minimum value of 1 and a maximum value of 10.

**So far I've tried the following:**

```
x = [1:1:10];
interp(x, 500 / length(x));
```

This, however, gives values above my maximum specified value of 10.

Is there any way I can get matlab to resample/interpolate solely between two points, without extending beyond them?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question but your example can be solved with `x=(1:1:10)';n=500;xi=interp1((1:numel(x))',x,linspace(1,numel(x),n)');`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you need to:

```
x=(1:1:10);
n=500;
xi=interp1(1:length(x),x,linspace(min(x),max(x),n));
```

Comment: I think that there is a mistake in your answer, I would write `[...],linspace(1,length(x),n));` instead.